# Changing background color opacity on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV that I'd like to change the background color opacity on, depending on if the mouse is over it or not.

I know you can use `background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5)` etc, but I want to set the colour separately. Is there any way I can JUST modify the OPACITY, and not the colour.

I could `opacity: 0.3`, etc, but that effects the whole DIV, and I just want to affect the background colour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No html/css doesn't have that option built in, but since you're accessing/setting the colour in javascript you might as well add in your own function which can handle that for you.

Here's an example for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RGBA(red,green,blue,alpha) {
    this.red = red;
    this.green = green;
    this.blue = blue;
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.getCSS = function() {
        return "rgba("+this.red+","+this.green+","+this.blue+","+this.alpha+")";
    }
}

// store a copy of the color
var bgColor = new RGBA(255,0,0,0.5);

function setBgOpacity(elem, opac) {
    bgColor.alpha = opac;
    elem.style.backgroundColor = bgColor.getCSS();
}
</script>
```

Then in the HTML use the `onmouseover` event to change the opacity of the bgColor:

```
<div onmouseover="setBgOpacity(this, '0.3');"
     onmousout="setBgOpacity(this, '0.5');">Put your mouse over me</div>
```

Comment: Just a small point to clarify things for those confused between 'opacity' and rgb 'alpha' - I'd rename the function from `setBgOpacity` to `setBgAlpha`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the background part of a different `div` and set the opacity of THAT `div`, i.e.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorum ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```css
#container { overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
#background { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:#FF0000;
}
#background:hover { opacity:0.3; }
#content { position:relative; z-index:10; }
```

Comment: #container { overflow:hidden; position:relative; }

Answer (score 2):

There a difference between the Alpha value in RGBa and Opacity. Opacity affects all child elements, Alpha does not.

You'll have to read the current colour value, then restate it as RGBa with the new Alpha value. You may need to convert the current hex colour value to a decimal triplet to do this.

Comment: No point when its easier to keep a copy of the colour and edit that instead. See my example http://stackoverflow.com/a/10388640/1031312

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between opacity and RGBa.

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on RGBA to modify the opacity of the background color, no, there is no way to set that separately from the color itself. You will have to declare explicit RGBA values for both your normal and hover states.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't edit only the alpha of rgba. So you should use the `RGB` part of the `RGBa`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate background colour from the container you may want to use `:before` or `:after`.

```
.container { 
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    &:hover {
        &:before {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    }

    .content {
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

When you hover on the `.container`, only the opacity of the `:before` is effected and not the contents.